# How long does it take for my command to run

Tags: shell, command-line, runtime, ksh

I want to run various command line tasks. How can I see how long a task takes to run and then cancel it conditionally from command line or bash script?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
SEC_MAX=10

command_foobar & _pid=$!

while kill -0 $_pid >/dev/null 2>&1; do
    ((CUR_SEC >= SEC_MAX)) && exit
    sleep 1
    ((CUR_SEC++))
done
```

For a better clarity, you can substitute

```
    ((CUR_SEC >= SEC_MAX)) && exit
```

by

```
    if ((CUR_SEC >= SEC_MAX)); then exit; fi
```

Comment: what about finding out the runtime for the command? Is there no easy way to do this? I want to show the exact runtime for various tasks. Killing the request was secondary. This would only drill down to seconds time granularity.

Comment: You can use `stat -c %Y /proc/$_pid` if you want. It's the epoch time of $_pid PID.

Answer (score 0):

regarding timing the command:

```
time yourCommand yourArguments
```

will print elapsed, user and system time of yourCommand. In ksh and bash it's a built-in, otherwise there's also `/usr/bin/time`.